# how to execute sed or awk commands in tcl without errors

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tcl

i wanted to print lines between two matches using sed or awk in tcl.
since sed is fastest way to do the job, i am tring to use sed in tcl. temp is the input file.

```
temp file:
Hello
1
2
3
work
4 5
6
7
```

```
sed -n '/Hello/,/work /p' temp
awk 's/Hello/,/work /' temp
```

this is working in shell, now i want to use this in tcl file,

```
tclsh exec sed -n {/Hello/,/work/p} temp
tclsh exec awk {/Hello/,/work/} temp
```

it is giving error as:

```
Missing }.
```

excepted output:

```
Hello
1
2
3
work
```

what am i missing here ?

Comment: It's probably something trivial, as it works when I try it by cutting and pasting into an interactive tclsh.

Comment: At a guess try `tclsh 'exec awk {/Hello/,/work/} temp'` so the shell doesn't interpret the string you're trying to pass to `tclsh` (whatever that is) before `tclsh` sees it.

Comment: @EdMorton, Hi thanks for the reply, this didnt work, its showing error: couldn't read file

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in pure tcl instead of trying to run an external program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Print text in between and including lines matching the regular
# expressions `begin` and `end`
proc print_between {filename begin end} {
    set inf [open $filename]
    set in_block false
    while {[gets $inf line] >= 0} {
        if {[regexp -- $begin $line]} {
            set in_block true
        }
        if {$in_block} {
            puts $line
            if {[regexp -- $end $line]} {
                set in_block false
            }
        }
    }
    close $inf
}

print_between temp Hello work
```